# How to make an offer on a NFT that’s not for sale

Tags: metaplex

I'm using metaplex and have to create a feature that allow users to make an offer on a NFT that isn't put on for sale.
I already implemented normal selling flow - `sell` and `execute-sale` with auction house, but how to generate an offer on a NFT that isn't put on for sale in programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in one of the answers, you can make a [`Buy order`](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFEUvCuC_A/KLVs_YdAlJwbSbvwaEk6pQ/view#17) similar to the sell order.

In Auction House, both the sell order (offer) and the buy order (bid) are represented using separate [Trade States](https://www.canva.com/design/DAFEUvCuC_A/KLVs_YdAlJwbSbvwaEk6pQ/view#11).

The beauty of separate buy and sell orders is that one can post a bid for a non-listed NFT one prefers. This allows for the non-sellers to allure attractive bids for their NFTs, and vice-versa allows buyers to attract otherwise non-interested sellers.

Answer (score 0):

Auction House is a program under Metaplex that uses a protocol called [stateless-offer](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/stateless-asks) in order to generate an offer on an NFT that isn't escrowed.

You can accomplish this by using [`buy`](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/auction-house/cli#buy) within Auction house to place an offer on an NFT that is not "for sale". The offer can then be executed using `execute-sale`.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thanks, `buy` can create an offer, and would you explain to me more details about how to accept / cancel the specific offer on the owner side? Maybe offers should be recognized by `txid` or something another?